# Unknown character in html inside webview android studio

Tags: android, html, android-studio

I view a lot of htmls with text inside, but there seems to be one html that is not displayed correctly, for some reason all the tilde characters display an unknown character, this is strictly related to that particular html document?

Since all the others htmls are viewed perfectly in webview, i guess it has nothing to do inside android studio?

[image]

Intial portion of html document

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
 <html><head>
 <link href="Content/watermark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">           
 <title>Código de Proceso Penal</title></head>
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

CADE

Comment: When i view the same html in google chrome for example, it is displayed perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to fact that **Webview** is not able to detect encoding.
If you are using Webview **loadData()** or  void **loadDataWithBaseURL()** method, try passing **"UTF-8"** as encoding, [you can check same here, on developer.android.com..](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

it this doesn't work try with **"iso-8859-1"** or **"iso-8859-15"** encoding